# Unable to do Time Machine backups from MacBook Pro on Mavericks

Tags: time-machine, backup, partition, time-capsule

I purchased a MacBook Pro Retina on March 2014 to replace my old MacBook.

Both were running Mavericks, but I decided to clone the disk into a partition on the new MacBook Pro and keep the ready installed software as a separate bootable backup partition. I have a 2 TB Time Capsule that I access the internet through. This did back up my new machine until a couple of months ago, and now is not found on the network even though it is still providing me with an internet connection.

In Airport Utility, the internet connection is shown along with an unaccessible Time Capsule. If I try to access the Time Capsule it says it was previously part of the network, but cannot be found if I scan for it. If I reboot into the other partition (my emergency boot) the Time Capsule is there and able to do backups.

Ideally I would like the Time Capsule to show up when I am working out of my main partition rather than the spare bootable but am unable to find any advice on how to correct this. I did successfully restore the main partition a couple of days ago after three days of failing to get Yosemite to work, so I know that it works fine through the other partition.

I am unsure on how to best move forward with this other than factory reset and hope. Does anyone have any less drastic solution?

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting Time Machine against a Time Capsule is a very slow process.

I like to just get a new USB drive and let Time Machine back up there and you can know if the problem is the Mac or the destination.

Doing that will help isolate what is causing the delay. I would also use a second machine to go into the Time Capsule and delete any "in progress" backups while your "problem Mac" is doing it's first backup to the USB drive.